# Error found when loading /home/juliet/.profile

Tags: bashrc

[image]

The image above is the error I get when I boot my system. Please does anyone know what this means? And how can I solve it?  The laptop is HP omen 15

Comment: There is an error in your `~/.bashrc` file. If you include the contents of this file in your question, it should be possible to figure out how to correct this.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I am getting error Permission denied so I don't know how to get the content of the file

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Which version of Ubuntu do you have on an HP Omen 15?

Answer (score 0):

From terminal edit and find error in line 1

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc or /home/juliet/.bashrc
```

Here is what I have on my first few line

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples
#
```

Start with just commenting ( # ) out the first line on your file and see how that goes.

Comment: This seem to work. Any idea what I need to do to stop error of permission denied when I try to execute bash?

Comment: Could just be a authorized user issue so try change into super user do or root user with : `sudo` and `sudo su -`